# Send emails from Rails 3 in development mode, offline?

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, email

I'm developing an app with email capabilities and I'd like to send emails to myself, locally (as in, I could completely disconnect my development machine from the internet and still have these test emails send and receive, just on my computer).

I imagine the Rails app sending to Mac OS X's built-in Linux CLI `mail` program, but I've no idea how to set this up.

I want to do this so I can send an unlimited number of test emails to myself without worrying about locking myself out of a GMail account or burning up free credit on Sendgrid, et al., or waiting for the message to make a round-trip to some server, etc.

Anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is it! [MockSMTP](http://mocksmtpapp.com/) (for OS X, at least)

---

UPDATE: This is arguably even better: [MailCatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher). As it is Ruby/Web powered, it's platform-agnostic, and doesn't require paying for a license for desktop software. Also, if you use it with Google Chrome, it employs WebSockets for live-updating when a new message arrives! Cool!

Comment: Forgot this was an option. MailCatcher is really the best way to do this for active development purposes. Your local machine isn't the place to be testing real email networking.

Answer (score 4):

Use [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/). It's a gem that runs on a local server (localhost:1080) and displays outgoing emails from a Rails app in a browser-rendered mock email client.

```
$ gem install mailcatcher
$ mailcatcher
```

1. Go to http://localhost:1080/
2. Send mail through smtp://localhost:1025

Answer (score 2):

While I don't run OS X myself I do work with OS Xers and we all use `sendmail` in development. All you need to do is configure it just for your development environment.

In `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
AppName::Application.configure do

  # …

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
    :location => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
    :arguments => '-i -t'
  }

end
```

Then in your mailer you can add a private method to determine who to email to if you are worried about accidentally emailing users/random email addresses:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer
  default :from => 'from.email@example.com'

  def welcome(user)
    @user = user
    mail(
      :subject => "Hello World",
      :to => recipient(@user.email)
    )
  end

private

  def recipient(email_address)
    return 'developer.email@example.com' if Rails.env.development?
    email_address
  end

end
```

Comment: Ok, I've configured my developement.rb file as you suggested, but I'm still getting no new mail when I check `mail` in the terminal. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: I did not know if you can use the mail command, as it is not actually an email tool.

Comment: I think you're mistaken there: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail I discovered I can check messages if I use my fully-addressed username on my local machine, as in, `system-user-name@my-macbook.local`, but I'd love it if all email addresses in development mode resolved to that address... thoughts?